# Why does an lvalue cast work?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, casting, assign, lvalue

I saw this kind of cast for the first time today, and I'm curious as to why this works. I thought casting in this manner would assign to the temporary, and not the class member. Using VC2010.

```
class A
{
public:

   A() :
      m_value(1.f)
   {
      ((float)m_value) = 10.f;
   }

   const float m_value;
};
```

Comment: Is that the exact snippet you tried? Normally this should error out because m_value is not initialized and should not compile the assignment.

Comment: http://liveworkspace.org/code/nVBzK$0, apparently it doesn't work

Comment: That **is not** allowed, and it should error out for multiple reasons (including the fact that `m_value` is not assigned a value in the initialization list)

Comment: Before your question, Didn't you need to initialize that `m_value` at A's constructor?

Comment: I edited to be what I actually used. It still assigns it. Glad to know my suspicions were correct.

Comment: I believe that's a GCC extension. It does not work under Clang. See [C/C++ Language Compatibility, lvalue cast](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#lvalue-cast)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't work. An explicit type conversion to `float` with cast notation will be a prvalue (§5.4):

> The result of the expression `(T)` *cast-expression* is of type `T`. The result is an lvalue if T is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type and an xvalue if T is an rvalue reference to object type; **otherwise the result is a prvalue**.

My emphasis added.

The assignment operator requires an lvalue as its left operand (§5.17):

> All require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand and return an lvalue referring to the left operand.

A prvalue is not an lvalue.

Answer (score 5):

Even after fixing all other problems to make the code compile, it only works in VC2010 because it uses a non-standard extension. And If you specify `/Wall` to see all warnings, you compiler will emit

> warning C4213: nonstandard extension used : cast on l-value