# void* cast to char* not lvalue?

Tags: c++, void-pointers, lvalue

I'm trying to make a function that takes a `void*`, copies some memory to it, and then moves the pointer. 
Since it is a void pointer, I thought I'd cast it to `char*` and move that, like so:

```
PVOID SendAndMoveHead(PVOID dest, const Message& message, const size_t& size)
{
    PVOID ret = CopyMemory(dest, (PVOID)message.msg.c_str(), size);
    ((char*)dest) += size;
    return ret;
}
```

However, VS complains about `((char*)dest)` saying

> expression must me a modifiable lvalue

which I thought it was, since the following works:

```
PVOID SendAndMoveHead(PVOID dest, const Message& message, const size_t& size)
{
    PVOID ret = CopyMemory(dest, (PVOID)message.msg.c_str(), size);
    char* d = (char*)dest;
    d += size;
    return (PVOID)d;
}
```

If someone could shed some light on why the first version shouldnt work I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: You cannot cast the left operand of the assignment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does an lvalue cast work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343276/why-does-an-lvalue-cast-work)

Comment: Arguably this should be tagged C, not C++.

Comment: @nwp - `const Message&` and `message.msg.c_str()` leaves no room for argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`((char*)dest)` gives you a new temporary `char *`. `((char*)dest) += size;` would change the temporary and have no effect, which causes a compilation failure.

In the second example `d` is not a temporary and lives long enough to get returned.

Alternatively you could write `return (char*)dest + size;`.